# Focus handling with Controls inside ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, focus, controltemplate

What is the proper way to manage the focus when you write your own control which has controls inside its control template?

---

Let's say we have a CustomControl with two TextBoxes in its ControlTemplate. As user and developer I would expect following behaviour:

1. When Calling customControl.Focus(), then the first TextBox in the template should receive focus.
2. Moving focus forward and backward using Tab / Shift+Tab is expected to work which means:

2.1 If the user presses Tab having focus in a control before the customControl, then focus should move to the first textbox of customControl.

2.2 If the user presses Shift+Tab having focus in the first textbox of custom control, then focus should move to any control before the customControl.

---

Following I tried already:

a. Setting the CustomControl to Focusable=false enables condition 2. but disables condition 1.

b. On StackOverflow the question how to move focus to a control inside the control template appears many times. Always proposing following solution:

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
  <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox1" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox1}" />
</Trigger>
```

This solution enables condition 1 and 2.1 but destroys condition 2.2.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Worth a read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx logical focus handling

Comment: Thank you for the link. I think I understand logical focus and introducing a focus scope doesn't solve the problem nor does it seem to me to be the proper way. Or is there another intention behind your link?

Comment: No special intention, but the logical scope is often ignored when it comes focus related things in terms.

Comment: Updating link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa969768(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You could go with the second option (the trigger on `IsFocused` property) and keep condition 2.2 satisfied by simply setting the `IsTabStop` property of your CustomControl to `False`. The big flaw in this solution though is that it can be easily undone by setting the `IsTabStop` property back to `True`.

The other way to achieve Your goal would be to drop the trigger and deal with focus changes in the control's code-behind like this:

```
protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotKeyboardFocus(e);
    if (e.NewFocus == this)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(e.OldFocus, Template.FindName("PART_TextBox1", this)))
            MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous));
        else
            MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest setting properties `IsTabStop={TemplateBinding IsTabStop}` and `TabIndex={TemplateBinding TabIndex}` on any focusable control in Your template, so that when any of these properties is set on your control, it still maintains the inner navigation order and prevents/allows navigating with TAB key to each of the inner controls.